# Add column number to every column

Tags: python, arrays, lambda

Im reading txt file and add array row by row. but I need to change every row like this
My list like = [[1strow],[2ndrow],[3rdrow],........,[8000throw]]. ıts like list in list.

My rows : Every row contain 23 letters but I only want to change 2-23 not first one.

```
e,a,b,c,d,r,y,t,w,s,e,t......s (23th letter , but If you start 0 cause of index, Its 22th)

t,y,e,e,s,f,g,r,t,q,w,e,r,.....s
```

What I want is

```
e,a1,b2,c3,d4,r5,y6,t7,w8,s9,e10,t11......s22

t,y1,e2,e3,s4,f5,g6,r7,t8,q9,w10,e11,r12,.....a22
```

My main code :

```
with open('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/input/mushrooms.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
            datas.append(row)

print(datas[0]) --> ['p', 'x', 's', 'n', 't', 'p', 'f', 'c', 'n', 'k', 'e', 'e', 's', 's', 'w', 'w', 'p', 'w', 'o', 'p', 'k', 's', 'u']
```

How can I do that with python ?

Comment: row = row[0:1] + ['%s%d' % (letter, i) for i, letter in enumerate(row[1:], 1)]

Comment: @rsiemens replace row[0] with row[0:1] because otherwise you are adding a string to a list instead of a list to a list

Comment: My mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
row = ['e','a','b','c','d','r','y','t','w','s','e','t']
newrow = row[0:1] + [letter + str(num) for num,letter in enumerate(row[1:],1)]
```

In your specific example,

```
newdatas = [row[0:1] + [letter + str(num) for num,letter in enumerate(row[1:],1)] for row in datas]
```